# How to use Electroserver's embedded Derby Database in AS3?

Tags: database, actionscript, flash-cs6, actionscript-3

I am trying to create an online multiplayer game with electroserver like here:

http://gamesfromjames.weebly.com/pickit.html

I was looking at the source code from electrotank. Unfortunately, I cannot compile it in flash CS6 because the document class is in mxml.(if someone can help me figure out how to test these examples  in pure as3 that would be great)  I did find these two functions in hte mxml class:

```
/**
         * Increases your rank by the amount specified by sending a properly formatted message to the plugin.
         */
        private function addToRankClicked():void {
            var ipr:PluginRequest = new PluginRequest();
            ipr.pluginName = "DatabasePlugin";

            var esob:EsObject = new EsObject();
            esob.setString(PluginConstants.ACTION, PluginConstants.TAG_ADD_TO_RANK);
            esob.setInteger(PluginConstants.TAG_ADD_TO_RANK, rankDeltaStepper.value);
            ipr.parameters = esob;
            _es.engine.send(ipr)

        }

        /**
         * Loads your rank from the database by asking the plugin for it.
         */
        private function getRank():void {
            var ipr:PluginRequest = new PluginRequest();
            ipr.pluginName = "DatabasePlugin";
            ipr.zoneId = -1;
            ipr.roomId = -1;

            var esob:EsObject = new EsObject();
            esob.setString(PluginConstants.ACTION, PluginConstants.TAG_GET_RANK);
            ipr.parameters = esob;
            _es.engine.send(ipr)
        }
```

Is this all that is needed to put things into the database and take things out or am I missing something?
If I was going to try to save the chat history and show it every time a user enters the chat room, how would I go about doing it with electroserver's derby database?

Thanks!

PS If Teresa is out there reading this you should reccommend they make an electroserver tag for this forum. Im not level 1500 yet..

Comment: I don't have enough rep to add an electroserver tag either, and there's a limit of 5 tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

The database parts of that example are all done in the extension, i.e the Java classes.  The two functions you quote are simply the client sending a plugin request to either ask for the user's current rank, or to increment that rank.

How familiar are you with SQL of any kind?  Derby is about the same as MySQL, etc.  You will need to design a database table for storing the data you want to persist, then implement Java and SQL similar to the example's code for storing the user's rank and updating it.